# How to get stack trace in Netbeans C++ IDE

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, netbeans-7, stack-trace

I am running a C++ project which is getting crashed often.

My environment : UBUNTU
IDE : Netbeans C++

I need to take a stack trace and send it to some one for reference to analyse the cause of crash. How to do it in Netbenas IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the error, Netbeans asks you about what to do with the signal received, you can `Discard and Pause`.
Then at the `Output` view (usually located below your code, or to the right), you can see a `Call Stack` tab.

There you can see your stack trace. Now, to take that stack trace in a text file, simply, click on an entry(a function) and the hit `Ctrl + A` and then `Ctrl + C` to select all the entries and copy them to your clipboard.

After that create a text file and then paste the stack trace in it, that's all!

*Let me know, if you need any more assistance.*